# Get node label name from csv file

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am importing csv file from import directory by cypher and I would like to create nodes with labels from csv file. Which would look something like this

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///B.csv" AS csv
CREATE (c:csv.Type {name:csv.Name})
return c
```

I know that this is wrong, but hope you can show me the right way to do it. I couldn't find any answer in both neo4j community and in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

from neo4j [community](https://community.neo4j.com/t/get-node-label-name-from-csv-file/41994) [dana.canzano](https://community.neo4j.com/badges/29/hot-link?username=dana.canzano)'s answer. It could be implemented by apoc library. Here is the code.

```
load csv with headers from 'file:///B.csv' as row 
call apoc.create.node([row.label],{name: row.name}) 
yield node return count(node);
```

You can find more details in community [page](https://community.neo4j.com/t/get-node-label-name-from-csv-file/41994)